# O que fazer quando isto acontecer?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-insert

Estou trabalhando em um sistema no qual devo cadastrar vários dados de um formulário em tabelas diferentes utilizando mysql. Funciona assim: A pessoa faz um cadastro e no mesmo formulário solicita um atendimento especial, Eu salvo os dados dele normalmente e com  o ID dele, que é gerado por auto-incremento, eu salvo os dados do pedido [id, usuario_id, pedido,...]. Se tudo sair corretamente, beleza. Mas a questão é, **e se sair errado o cadastro do pedido? Devo excluir o usuário, dar a mensagem de erro e retornar para o cadastro para que ele cadastre novamente? Qual a melhor saída para isto?**

Comment: Eu acho que deve considerar o que pode dar errado e trabalhar para que o erro não aconteça e direcionar o usuário para o ponto que falta para ficar ok

Comment: O ideal é que tudo isto esteja numa transação, assim se falhar uma você da um rollback, nada será feito. A segunda questão é investigar o que causou o problema, para isso registre nos logs o maior numero de detalhes possíveis, se utilizar serviços externos (NewRelic) utilize-os também para investigar o que ocorreu. Uma vez que o erro ocorreu normalmente o usuário reenviar não resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Bem, vamos ver se eu entendi...
vc recebe dados de um formulário exemplo: **nome,cpf, pedido, categoria**
no caso vc deseja salvar **nome** e **cpf** em uma tabela e **pedido** e **categoria** em outra correto?

então:

salva nome,cpf na tabela1

verifica **se** foi gerado o id da tabela1 
caso tenha sido gerado, pega esse id

e usa para salvar o pedido, categoria na tabela2

caso dê algum erro ao salvar na tabela2 o correto seria excluir a linha da tabela1 onde id seja o que vc pegou
e depois mostre uma mensagem para o cliente dizendo que houve um problema no cadastro e que ele deve tentar novamente.

espero ter ajudado!!!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Foi exatamente isto que eu fiz, mas achei meio "gambiarra" fazer assim... Pensei que pudesse ter outra forma, mas acho que vou ter que deixar assim mesmo.